# Why does map become empty outside the (switch) case?

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, g++, c++17

I have the following code, where I initialize my map, `inserts` and view whether the data has been enter correctly in the first case. And then I view my data again in case 2, but it shows that it is empty in case 2, but is present in Case 1. I have never seen this kind of behavior.

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        int n, m;
        cin>>n>>m;
        while(m--) {
            string s;
            map<vector<int>, int> inserts;
            int x, y, z, W;
            int x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;
            cin>>s;
            switch(resolveOptions(s)) {
                case update:
                    cin>>x>>y>>z>>W;
                    inserts.insert({{x,y,z}, W});
                    cout<<"Inserts in u: ";
                    showInserts(inserts);
                break;
                case query:
                    cin>>x1>>y1>>x1>>x2>>y2>>z2;
                    cout<<"inserts in q";
                    showInserts(inserts);
                // calculateSum(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, inserts)<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `showInserts(inserts)` shows the map

I'm not used to programming in C++.

Comment: Please note that 'substantial' edits to your question *after* answers have been posted can cause problems. Such changes can invalidate answers that were posted in good faith. In this case, there is no real damage done but you should be aware of the potential consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `map<vector<int>, int> inserts;` declares a variable that is **local** to the function in which it occurs. Each time that function is called, a new 'version' of the variable is created (and initialized as an empty map). When the function returns, the `inserts` object is destroyed.

If you want the `inserts` object to retain its value(s) between function calls, you will need to declare it as a global variable (outside/before the function).

---

The same principle holds for a variable that is declared inside a `for` or `while` loop: the *scope* of that variable is **one iteration of the loop**; each time the loop runs, a new instance of the variable is created and, when each **iteration** of the loop ends, the variable is destroyed. In this case, you need to declare and initialize the variable outside/before the loop.

Comment: please check the code again, this is the actual code

Comment: @VedantK Well, with some minor modifications, my answer still holds. (Assuming the code you have shown is the body of a function.)

Comment: the code is inside a loop, all within the same function. No function calls, basically

Comment: @VedantK See edit: the same 'principle' is at work - you are declaring a new **local** variable each time you run the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
map<vector<int>, int> inserts;
void test(int n) {

    int x, y, z, W;
    int x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;
    cin>>s;
    switch(resolveOptions(s)) {
        case update:
            cin>>x>>y>>z>>W;
            inserts.insert({{x,y,z}, W});
            cout<<"Inserts in u: ";
            showInserts(inserts);
            break;
        case query:
            cin>>x1>>y1>>x1>>x2>>y2>>z2;
            cout<<"inserts in q";
            showInserts(inserts);
            // calculateSum(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, inserts)<<endl;
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    test(1);
    test(2);
}
```

Just declare map<vector, int> inserts; globaly to retain its value.

Comment: please check the code again, this is the actual code

Comment: Updated answer @VedantK. I hope you have all remaining functions in code.